# Automatically create a new object from GridSearchCV best_params_

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Assume I want to fit a random forest, `RFC`, and grid search using sklearns `GridSearchCV`.
We can get the best parameters using `RFC.best_params_` but if I then want to create a random forest I need manually to write those parameters in e.g `RFC(n_estimators=12,max_depth=7)` afterwards. Is there a way,something like `RFC_opt=RFC(best_params_)` to do it automatically?

Comment: Sklearn sets a default value for all the hyperparameters, but if you want to change them you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, if you unpack the parameters it is doable, i.e if

`best_par=RFC_grid_search.best_params_` then you can create the optimal RFC with the parameters in `best_params_` by
`rfc_opt=RFC(**best_part)`